# Android: how to Fix Gradle execution error?

Tags: android, gradle

I have Android Studio installed on  my PC and it has been working fine.  I just opened up Android Studio (v2.3.2) and now my projects won't build/sync.

> Error message says Gradle project sync failed. Failed to complete
>   Gradle execution.  Cause: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but the error occurred after I loaded a Samsung USB Driver onto my computer so that I can connect my Samsung device to Android Studio for testing my projects.  Any ideas how to get back up and running again?

Here is additional error message:

Error: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

And the setting in Android Studio for File \ Other Settings \ Default Project Structure \ JDK location: is set to "Use embedded JDK" which is at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre".

Gradle info.:

```
build.gradle (Project)


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle (Module: app)

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jdw.v060B"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: try to change version to 2.2 not sure but i hope it work

Comment: Try using this : ./gradlew --stacktrace --info.  Which will give you information about your problem

Comment: @Terril Thomas What do you mean?  How do I use it?

Comment: The below command can be used in your terminal/ CMD. For windows use gradlew --stacktrace --info

Comment: Ok.  Do I have to run it in a specific directory?  When I run it from the C:\ I get error message "./gradlew --stacktrace is not recognized..."

Comment: have you installed gradle?
can you post some of the codes in your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your gradle-wrapper.properties, check there distribution url must be greater than 3.0 or you use this

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: Yes, that file has exactly the information you've have listed.

Comment: try to invalidate the cache and restart Android Studio it will clear the temp Gradle file and download the new one and build the app.

Comment: I just tried that and no luck but I did get an additional error message that appears related to not finding java:  Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'  I posted the full message above.

Comment: Question, I just switched to a new PC with an Intel CPU.  But I originally created the project on a different PC that had an AMD CPU.  Could that be the reason I am having a problem?